# Image slices placed using CSS Divs

Tags: css, image, html, css-position

Right now many of my designs used sliced graphics with absolute positioned DIVs.

```
<style>
    #Slice-01 {
        position: absolute;
        left:0; top:0;
        width:214px; height:38px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="Slice-01">
        <img src="/slices/Slice_01.jpg" width="214" height="38" alt="" border="0" />
    </div>
</body>
```

I've seen an alternate method where the image is the background of the DIV instead of an object inside the DIV...

```
<style>
    #Slice-01 {
        position: absolute;
        left:0; top:0;
        width:214px; height:38px;
        background-image: url(/slices/Slice_01.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="Slice-01"></div>
</body>
```

The only practical difference I can see is that one can drag the image out of the browser window on the first example but cannot when it's the background image.

Questions:

1. What's the more commonly accepted method and why?
2. What are the pros and cons of each method?

Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To me the second is more semantic and thus would be a better method

2) Pros of Image method:

- none really

Cons:

- Congested code and bad maintainability

Pros of CSS:

- Semantic
- Easy to maintain

Cons:

- None

Comment: You don't believe there's anything wrong with an intentionally empty DIV container?  This seems counterintuitive to me and why I posted the question.  I agree... the second is easier to maintain.  Thank-you.

Comment: @Sparky672 not at all - thats what divs were made for was layout purposes, to stop people using tables and other tags, so your solution is completely standard :)

Comment: Ok thank-you!  It's very clean although it's still hard wrapping my head around intentionally leaving a DIV empty... like maybe some situation where a browser would ignore an empty DIV.

Comment: @Sparky672 Doesn't happen man ;) Div's were made SPECIFICALLY as layout elements :)

Comment: Yeah I know, but every day I think I have something all figured out and then some version of Internet Explorer makes a liar out of me.  Thanks again.